# Bigquery Change date based on a condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I incorporate the below statement in my existing query to add 1 year to a date based on a condition

Condition: Add 1 year to CalendarDate when Version = 'ACTA'

``
---This adds 1 year to existing date----

CASE WHEN VERSION = 'ACTA' then (SELECT DATE_ADD(CalendarDate, INTERVAL 12 month)) ELSE T1.CALENDAR_DATE END as CalendarDate,
``

```
(WITH TempTable AS
 (SELECT 'ACT' as Version, '2021-06-30' as CalendarDate UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ACTA', '2020-06-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TAR', '2021-06-30')
  
SELECT * FROM TempTable)
```

Result:

| Row | Version | CalendarDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ACT | 2021-06-30 |
| 2 | ACTA | 2020-06-30 |
| 3 | TAR | 2021-06-30 |

I want to add one year to CalendarDate where Version = ACTA

Final Result:

| Row | Version | CalendarDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ACT | 2021-06-30 |
| 2 | **ACTA | 2021-06-30** |
| 3 | TAR | 2021-06-30 |

Comment: Thanks logic seems fine, how do i incorporate in my current query? the current query generates the result in table 1.

Answer (score 1):

The logic seems like:

```
(CASE WHEN VERSION = 'ACTA' 
      THEN DATE_ADD(CalendarDate, INTERVAL 12 month)
      ELSE T1.CALENDAR_DATE
 END) as CalendarDate,
```

Comment: Thanks logic seems fine, how do i incorporate in my current query? the current query generates the result in table 1

Comment: You would put the expression in the part where you have `select * from table1`.